# How do I redesign this highchart

Tags: highcharts

EDIT:

How do i bring the bottom graph to the right of the top chart and align them as if they look like one chart

http://jsfiddle.net/dP93u/

```
<div><div id="container1" style="width: 300px; height: 400px;"></div><div id="container" style="width: 300px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div></div>
```

New EDIT:

The only way i can change the answer is if someone can develop the same chart in just one container div instead of 2.

Comment: While I dig around for my example code what you can do is create 2 separate charts but only have on xAxis enabled and offset the charts such that they line up.

Comment: I can definitely try that out but I hope the loading of the chart make it seamless as if they are one cohesive unit instead of two separate entities. Thanks for looking in.

Comment: I cannot find the one I am looking for but you can use this as base: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/Z8V3v/. This is one chart not two.

Comment: Why you cannot build it in this way: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack - that should be faster and more complex.

Comment: @codename I agree with you buddy ... but as you know design req. are design req. I as a developer don't have too much of a say on that. Though i did suggest this to them only to be turned down :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to build two barcharts, set their offset such that they get aligned, take care that only one will have the xAxis.

Hope this will be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks i have got what i needed. Thanks. Please refer to my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dP93u/3/

Answer (score 1):

If you would't mind including bootstrap.css library, the solution is pretty simple. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/H9wCx/) fiddle.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend: how can I have value labels between the two bar series?
You can done it via css:

```
<div style="font-family:verdana">
<p style="text-align:center">Population pyramid for Germany, midyear 2010</p>
<p style="font-size:small;text-align:center">Source: www.census.gov</p>
<div id="container1" style="width: 50%; height: 400px;float:left"></div>
<div id="container" style="width: 50%; height: 400px;float:left;position:relative;left:-55px"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

and some refinements of HighCharts code. See [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dP93u/6/).