# Highcharts: Offset origin for positive and negative values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This is what I am aiming for:

[image: bar chart]

I want to have the labels on the 0-Axis. Is there a way to offset bars based on positive/negative values? I guess I should look for a callback to hook into but wasn't successful in finding one.

Any help is appreciated!

```
Basic bar chart fiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QGnmM/

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19432260/1608670

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would come at this a different way. How about 2 charts? One to handle negative and the othe to handle positive values? You then remove the xAxis labels from one and set the `x` value on the other. Essentially you would set up the containers as:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="container1" style="height: 400px; width:200px"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="container2" style="height: 400px; width:200px"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then you make two charts:

```
$('#container1').highcharts({...});
$('#container2').highcharts({...});
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/jpDjW/). Things to keep in mind - turn off everything.
Note that I did this in each chart. But, you could do this in a global options dialogue as well.

Comment: Quite creative solution :p

Comment: Two bar charts using same config [Click here for jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jpDjW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect (overlap issue) but you can use **x** and **y** in **labels** to adjust the position of labels :http://jsfiddle.net/Tm6Gk/

```
  "xAxis": {
    "tickLength": 0,
    "labels": {
        "x": 150,
        "y": 0,
    ...
```